# avoid inner classes

Tags: python, object-oriented

I'm trying to implement method chaining with classes, but struggle to make it without inner classes.

Specifically, I have three classes:

- a class for different data loading
- a class for computation of mathematical properties

I'm not sure how to implement exactly, but I have an intuitive structure in mind:

```
obj = Object()

obj.data.square() -> will upload data from a file to draw a square
obj.data.circle() -> will upload data from a file to draw a circle

obj.data.square().geometry.area() -> will compute an area of a square
obj.data.square().geometry.perimeter() -> will compute a perimeter of a square
obj.data.circle().geometry.area() -> will compute an area of a circle
obj.data.circle().geometry.perimeter() -> will compute a perimeter of a circle
```

Importantly, the classes "Data()" and "Geometry()" can be modified in the future. For example, I can upload other figures, such as a triangle:

```
obj.data.triangle()
```

Or to compute other geometric properties, such as centre of mass, or volume:

```
obj.data.triangle().geometry.centre_of_mass()
```

For example, having the Geometry class:

```
class Geometry():
     def area():
         return....
     def perimeter():
         return....
     def centre_of_mass():
         return....
     def volume():
         return....
```

I'm not very familiar with OOP in Python, so any suggestions on how structure my code will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "inner classes", you mean something like:

```py
class Outer:
    class Inner:
        pass
```

In general, this pattern only buys you a nesting for the class names, but should not be required to give your classes the interface you desire.

What I think you need to do is clarify which piece of code is responsible for each of (a) the values that are necessary to do the computation, e.g. side-lengths and radii, and (b) the logic to do the computations you desire.

From what I glean from the question, it is not clear where (a) should enter the picture, but I would expect it makes the most sense where the `square`/`circle`/etc is called. So let's start from the top:

1. Don't add ambiguous, unnecessary classes like `Data` or `Object` to your implementation unless you need them. It seems you just need a module with some shape classes in it:

```py
# Give your file a name better than `data` or `obj`, why not `shapes.py`?

class Circle:
    ...
class Square:
    ...
```

2. Do you need a separate class for each shapes "geometry"? If the goal is to keep the data separate from the calculation logic (a reasonable want), that goal is betrayed already by containing a `geometry` attribute which has those functions. In other words you have 2 options here, one which doesn't seem like what you are looking for, but I will mention for completeness:

```py
class Square:
    # Data-only class
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.side_length = side_length

# Note: a whole nother discussion on the interface for the calc functions
```

Or, more in line with the interface outlined in your question:

````py
class ShapeGeometry;
    def area(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Square(ShapeGeometry):
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.side_length = side_length
    def area(self):
        ...
```
````

Comment: Please note, questions involving stub code are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.